# ClasNotFound Exception in jar

Tags: maven, hadoop, jar

I have the following pom.xml.

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.datasys.prasanna</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-wordcount</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>hadoop-wordcount</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.1</version>
      </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I create a jar like mvn package, I get a jar named `hadoop-wordcount-1.0.0.jar`
But when I try to run the jar like hadoop jar hadoop-wordcount-1.0.0.jar WordCount /input /out1

It says `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount`

**WordCount** is the java file which has my main method. Am I missing out something in pom.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your WordCount class is in a (Java) package (for example, if you copied and pasted code from [this example](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount)), then you'll need to provide the fully qualified class name on the command line.

For example:

```
hadoop jar hadoop-wordcount-1.0.0.jar org.myorg.WordCount /input /out1
```

Comment: I did not use that example code. But giving the fully qualified class name works.